# Encryption C# web config fails

Tags: c#, encryption, web-config

I tried to encrypt web.config using the commands

```
cd C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319

aspnet_regiis.exe -pc "CustomKeys16" -exp

aspnet_regiis.exe -pa "CustomKeys16" "NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE"

aspnet_regiis -pef "connectionStrings" "C:\Users\cnandy\Desktop\Test\Websites\AccountDeduplicationWeb" -prov "CustomProvider"

aspnet_regiis -px "CustomKeys16" "C:\Users\cnandy\Desktop\New folder\encrypt.xml" -pri
```

they work fine first time. 
Now after decryption and changing something in the web config connection string if I again try to encrypt using the commands it shows the errors.

[image]

Please help as I am running out of ideas. 
Can't be it possible to re-run the encryption after modifying web.config ?

Comment: I tried changing everything from the key container name to the Encryption Provider Name but with no luck :(

Comment: Is there someone who can help with this ?